# Getting WCF Service Metadata

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm working with a WCF service. I do not have access to the service. Only a URL like `https://test.my-domain.com/services/my-service.svc`. I vaguely remember there being a way to see what actions a WCF service exposed. Kind of like the metadata or something like that.

How do I request that metadata?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append `?wsdl` to the url and check it out in a browser. But it can be different if WCF is configured to use a different metadata publishing URL. In code, you can use the `MetadataExchangeClient` class, which can discover WSDL documents but it can also discover MEX metadata (it also depends on the exact URL, could be `...xxx.svc/mex` or anything else).